# Is there a way to remove an element in a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
a = ['hi', ['item1', 'item2']]
```

I'm trying to use `a.remove()` to remove the first element 'hi' from the list and iterate over the inner list, and I have to generalize it since I'll be using more of these. However, I'm not able to get it.

```
a = a.remove(a[0])
for each_item in a:
    for item in each_item:
        print(item)
```

I thought would return

```
item1
item2
```

But it instead returns

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I need to be able to generalize it. That is, I need to be able to remove the first element of that list, and be able to print the other elements in the list of the list

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: because `remove` method returns `None` and you have assigned `None` to a. You should remove the assignment.

Comment: I'm quite new, so could you explain with more details?

Comment: Not sure you're use case, but it would be more common to leave `a` alone and just iterate over the part you need: `for each_item in a[1:]:` This starts the iteration at the second element, but doesn't mutate the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.remove` doesn't return array without removed value. It returns None as remove item in place.

Incorrect: `a = a.remove('hi)`.

Correct: `a.remove('hi')`

Comment: Works, thanks. But I don't get what the issue is with ```a = a.remove```